# How to go through the collection without using any loop construct?

Tags: java

A java interview question. Is there any way in java programming other then the loop constructs to iterate through a given collection(an Array) and work on the each element of the collection.

Comment: Does "goto" qualify as a "loop" construct? :)

Comment: @Nick there's no goto in Java.

Comment: Obviously ... a sane programmer doesn't do these things in a real program :-)

Comment: @pingw33n -- correct. I was thinking of continue/break labels -- which *are* part of a loop construct.

Comment: @pingw33n There _is_ a `goto` statement in Java which can only be used to go to the beginning of a loop.  I did use it once with two `for` loops when I wanted to `break` to the outer loop.

Comment: @toto, There are `goto` and `const` keywords which you cannot use *anywhere* in code.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: OK.  I made the same mistake as @pingw33n: I thought I had used `goto` in the past, but it was actually `break someLabel;`.

Comment: @toto I didn't make any mistake here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Recursion is one way to do it

```
void it(Iterator i) {
    if (i.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(i.next());
        it(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: I would point out these even though you can do this, anyone who does this in a real system deserves to be sacked. :P

Answer (score 5):

Other than recursion commons-collection has utility methods that you may use to do stuff on a collection. Note that this api also uses loop constructs internally. But the client code would look like :

```
CollectionUtils.forAllDo(
   yourCollection,
   new Closure() {
      void execute(java.lang.Object element) {
      // do smt with element
      }
   }
);
```

Check the CollectionUtils here : http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/Closure.html

Comment: +1 I like this... the awkward left-handed not-what-anybody-was-expecting approach. I'll just trust it works.

Answer (score 3):

[Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could recursively go through a function to get the same functionality:

```
public void iterate(int[] array, int index){
    if (index >= array.length){
        return;
    }else{
        //work with element at array[index]
        iterate(array, index+1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can interchange an iterative solution for a recursive one.  Loops are iterative, so just create a recursive solution instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion we iterate array or collection without using loop.
See below recursion method:

```
public static void iterateArray(int nums[], int index) {

    if (nums.length == index) {

        return;
    }
    System.out.print(nums[index] + " ");
    iterateArray(nums, index + 1);

}
```